# Mysql remove auto increment from all tables dynamically

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I wish to remove auto increment for all tables in a database dynamically.  I've seen examples like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE my_col my_col **INT(10)** UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

But I wish to do this to all tables automatically, as the length of some of the primary key columns is different (INT(11), INT(5), etc).

Comment: It's certainly possible using a script and clever use of the `information_schema` database, but I think I would recommend dumping the database with `mysqldump`, then just using a stream editor or search/replace to remove all the `auto_increment` keywords, drop the database and reload from the modified dumpfile.

Comment: I'm also curious why anyone would ever want to perform such an operation... you know that you can provide explicit values for `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns (only if no value is explicitly provided does MySQL use the next value in the sequence)?

Comment: Adding to @eggyal's comment, note that the number in parantheses doesn't affect your data in any way. It only affects how it will be displayed by some applications. If the application is yours - you usually don't need to care about this value at all. It can be 2 or 11 - the values and the possible ranges will remain the same.